# How to restore the class of associations from an ActiveModel object serialized into JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, activemodel

I have a class including ActiveModel that needs to have some "associations", like this:

```
a      = ActiveModelClass.new
a.user = User.find(1)
```

I'm just using an attr_accessor for this:

```
attr_accessor :user

### Elsewhere ###

a.user.name # => "Kevin"
```

So far so good. But now I want to serialize it into JSON:

```
json = a.to_json
b    = ActiveModelClass.new(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json))
```

But now, user is a hash:

```
b.user.class # => Hash
```

How can I cleanly restore these "associations" as objects of the classes they originally were?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused: I have a feeling you've abstracted your example to the point where it's just hard to understand.  Do you have something like this?

```
b.user 
=> {:name => "Kevin", :email => "kev@foo.foo"}
```

?

if so, you can make a user object out of this hash just by passing it to the .new or .create method:

```
user = User.create(b.user)
```

You can then do what you want with this user object, including setting b.user equal to it.